# Creating a relationship between 2 newly created nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I need to create a relationship between two newly created nodes,but it's creating another two nodes without creating a relationship between them.
I need to know how to get data from `py2neo` `cypher` query

```
def enter_products():  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json(True)
        params = {"data": {"name":data['name']}}
        products=graph.cypher.execute(" create(a:Products {data}) RETURN (a)", params)
        CR_brand= {"data": {"brand":data['brand']}}
        brands=graph.cypher.execute("merge(b:Brand {brand:{data}.brand}) 
    RETURN (b)",CR_brand)
        relation_brand=graph.cypher.execute("create(a:name)-[c:product_of]->(b:brand)")
        RETURN 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You either can do it all in one statement:

```
create(a:Products {data})
merge(b:Brand {brand:{data}.brand}
create(a)-[:product_of]->(b)
```

or you have to look up by their key-property.

```
create(a:Products {name:{data}.name})-[c:product_of]->(b:Brand {data}.brand)
```